# How often to I commit in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am deleting a large amount of data from the a large Oracle database. The process I have followed is that I delete a record table A with causes CASCADE delete on table B which has CASCADE delete on some other table. So basically there are several tables related with each other with CASCADE delete.

Currently this process works in iteration for a number of records in table A and I only COMMIT at the very end of the iteration (when all data is deleted). The process takes around 30 hours to complete.

I have been suggested to have regular COMMIT, i.e. a COMMIT for each record deletion for table A (including deletion on any subsequent records in child tables).

I know that regular commit will keep the undo log size low but is there any performance improvement with regular commits? Would I see an improvement in the time it takes to complete the script?

Comment: The undo log is a concern, but the main tradeoff seems to me the chance that the `DELETE` script might fail versus the overhead of `COMMIT`ting each record.  I would suggest that it's probably a good idea to `COMMIT` after a certain batch of records have been `DELETE`d.  If your `DELETE` script fails, then you can restart with the batch that failed, and not have to `ROLLBACK` the entire humongous transaction.

Comment: How does the colleague who suggested it answers these questions, and why?

Comment: I found [this article](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022) interesting. It even suggests that regular `COMMIT` results in a larger redo files, although this related to 9i whereas I am doing it on 10g

Answer (score 6):

Frequent commits would not be expected to improve the performance of your code.  Doing a large number of interim commits could well slow down your code by forcing you to spend more time waiting on sync operations.  And if you commit in the middle, you likely have to write quite a bit of code to ensure that your code is fully restartable.

Do you have an AWR or statspack snapshot or a trace file that shows what you're actually waiting on?  30 hours to do anything seems unreasonable.  That would lead me to strongly suspect that you're missing some indexes that are causing your cascaded deletes to do full table scans every time a row is deleted.  Fixing the missing indexes or doing multi-row deletes so that you have to do full table scans less frequently would seem far more likely to improve performance than worrying about when changes are committed.

Comment: I'm not agree with you about the first part of your comment. Do some intermediate commit during your batch is a good solution if the time for delete is 30 hours. The probability to have an incident during this period (undo, disconnect..) is high and the rollback will be huge.  Do some commit will not improve or lowest performance but it will secure it.

Comment: @eliatou - It is certainly true that interim commits in a 30 hour process, assuming you write the code to make your process restartable, would allow you to more easily restart the process if it errors out in the middle.  That does not contradict what I said, though.  It doesn't improve the performance of your code, it adds a small penalty in the general case.  That penalty may well be worth it, of course, but it's a penalty.  30 hours strikes me as so vastly out of whack, though, that I'd focus on tuning that before even contemplating adding restartability.

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave and eliatou. I don't have an AWR report, but your suggestions make sense.Regarding the indexes, most of the tables are indexed properly but I have few tables composite primary keys based on foreign keys and each of that column in individually indexed (table doesn't have it's own primary key). These are large tables and I noticed that even selecting data from this table takes a very long time (i.e. several hours to load all data). So I was wondering if that might be causing the delay.

Comment: Anyway,  I have added some commits and running the script again, so lets see how long does it take.